# MKMapAnnotationView - how to support dark mode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview, apple-maps

I have Apple's `mapView` and custom markers displayed in it. Each marker has 2 images in Assets for the dark and light mode appropriately. The problem is that **markers do not react to the dark/light mode theme changes**. What I've tried:

- reload input views of mapView inside method `traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)`
- resetting image in the marker view class inside method `traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)`

SO, how can I update markers when the theme changes?

Answer (score 4):

I've just found the same thing, so I've modified my `MKAnnotationView`-derived class to handle it:

```
class MapPinView: MKAnnotationView {
    
    // MKAnnotationView doesn't seem to automatically use the correct image for dark mode, so we have to ensure it does
    var combinedImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            updateImage()
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        if let imageName = selected ? "pushPinSelected" : "pushPin",
            let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
            self.combinedImage = image
        }
    }
    
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle {
            updateImage()
        }
    }
    
    private func updateImage() {
        image = combinedImage?.imageAsset?.image(with: traitCollection) ?? combinedImage
        if let image = self.image {
            centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -image.size.height / 2.0)
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I also initialise the `combinedImage`, when creating the MapPinView:

```
extension MapView: MKMapViewDelegate {
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {    
        let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: Constants.annotationId, for: annotation) as! MapPinView
        annotationView.combinedImage = UIImage(named: "pushPin")            
        return annotationView
    }
...
```